# Is it possible to use bash to search for a certain phrase on a website?

Tags: bash, web

I was just curious if this was possible. I have tried googling it, but nothing seems to show up. I'd also rather not download the site beforehand and just through the html file that way.

Comment: `curl url | grep pattern` ?

Comment: I guess you can combine `curl` and `grep` to do such a thing if there is no js that needs to be interpreted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `curl <url> | grep <pattern>` as another user detailed.

But be cognizant that that will show all matching results, which may not be ideal.

If you want to match the first (or a select set of results), use `curl<url>  | grep -m <count> <pattern>`.

For example: `curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927008/is-it-possible-to-use-bash-to-search-for-a-certain-phrase-on-a-website | grep -m 1 "possible"` will only return the first match.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'm a little new to bash, this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy enough

```
 curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927008/is-it-possible-to-use-bash-to-search-for-a-certain-phrase-on-a-website | grep possible
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!